# jquery open links in new window not working

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, safari, document-ready

I have a page with a checkbox that is by default `checked` on page load that indicates whether ALL page links will open in same window or new tab/window (based on user's browser settings). If the box is checked, the links open in a new tab/window, if it is not checked, they will open in same window. Very simple.

HTML

```
<label>Open links in new page:
<input type="checkbox" id="link-pref" checked><span></span>
</label>
```

Using jquery, I have function in `$(document).ready()` that will perform the work of opening the links appropriately depending on the checkbox state.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        if ($('#link-pref').is(":checked")){$(this).attr("target","_blank");}
        else{$(this).attr("target","_parent");}
    });
});
```

The problem I am having is that it seems to be working sporadically in desktop browsers, and in Safari (mobile) doesn't really seem to be working at all. The links just open in the same window, regardless of whether the box is checked or not.

According to my research, this SHOULD be working and SHOULD be opening all links on this page in a new tab if the box is checked. But such is not the case, especially in Safari-mobile. Thoughts, ideas?

UPDATE: It seems that the only links that are not opening accordingly in Safari are those which are loaded into a div using an ajax call. The ajax call is being made before the link-opening statement in the `$(document).ready()` block, so I still see no reason why this would not be working.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "links.cgi",
        success: function(result){
            $('#linktable').html(result);
    }});

    $("a").click(function(){
        if ($('#link-pref').is(":checked")){$(this).attr("target","_blank");}
        else{$(this).attr("target","_parent");}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is once you click the link it starts opening the link before your code executes. I'd change the target attribute when the checkbox is changed, not on the link click.

```
$('#link-pref').change(function(){
    if ($('#link-pref').is(":checked")){$('a').attr("target","_blank");}
    else{$('a').attr("target","_parent");}
})
```

EDIT: The events aren't being attached to your ajax produced elements because the attachment happens on page load. You'd have to call the attachment function again after your ajax calls if you wanted to attach events to them, but I'd still use my above solution. You'll still have to call a function that changes the target of all link elements every time you add a new element to the page though.

Comment: And as for handling the initial load, just add that statement in the success block of the ajax call, rather than independantly afterward?

Comment: Yah, make sure the success block of the ajax call sets the target to the correct value based on the value of  `$('#link-pref').is(":checked")` for any new elements. Then if there's a listener on `$('#link-pref').change()` that toggles the link targets, they'll always have the correct value.

Comment: Thank you dave...all seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

W3C says every html attribute MUST have a value. Unless your page is html5 (in which case, some browser might not render it correctly), this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="link-pref" checked>
```

should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="link-pref" checked="checked">
```

if you omit the value, some brosers could not understand your markup code.

Comment: I have updated accordingly and it makes no difference. Thanks though.

Comment: can you try wrapping your script in $(window).load(....)  instead of document ready?